# using drools in gradle project,it's error when i'm packing a jar and running

Tags: java, gradle, drools

I use drools in my gradle project, it's normal when I'm running locally, but it's error when I'm packing a jar and running.
I use the following version

```
compile group: 'org.kie', name: 'kie-spring', version: '7.17.0.Final'
compile group: 'org.drools', name: 'drools-core', version: '7.17.0.Final'
compile group: 'org.kie', name: 'kie-ci', version: '7.17.0.Final'
```

the error log is as follows:

```
2022-09-23 18:55:17.183  INFO [1LSHENYUEWANG.local-192.168.100.2] [main-1] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : [] Adding Service org.kie.internal.services.KieWeaversImpl

2022-09-23 18:55:17.197  INFO [1LSHENYUEWANG.local-192.168.100.2] [main-1] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : [] Adding Service org.kie.internal.services.KieBeliefsImpl

[Byte Buddy] ERROR org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping$__sisu4 [ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]], null, loaded=false]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot resolve type description for org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping
    at net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Resolution$Illegal.resolve(TypePool.java:157)
    at net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default$WithLazyResolution$LazyTypeDescription.delegate(TypePool.java:912)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$AbstractBase$OfSimpleType$WithDelegation.getSuperClass(TypeDescription.java:8292)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$AbstractBase.isAssignable(TypeDescription.java:7663)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$AbstractBase.isAssignableFrom(TypeDescription.java:7690)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$ForLoadedType.isAssignableFrom(TypeDescription.java:8536)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$AbstractBase.isAssignable(TypeDescription.java:7664)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$AbstractBase.isAssignableTo(TypeDescription.java:7704)
    at net.bytebuddy.matcher.SubTypeMatcher.matches(SubTypeMatcher.java:47)
    at net.bytebuddy.matcher.SubTypeMatcher.matches(SubTypeMatcher.java:26)
    at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatcher$Junction$Conjunction.matches(ElementMatcher.java:122)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$RawMatcher$ForElementMatchers.matches(AgentBuilder.java:1312)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.doTransform(AgentBuilder.java:10343)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.transform(AgentBuilder.java:10302)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.access$1600(AgentBuilder.java:10068)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$LegacyVmDispatcher.run(AgentBuilder.java:10687)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$LegacyVmDispatcher.run(AgentBuilder.java:10634)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.transform(AgentBuilder.java:10225)
    at com.ddmc.monitor.enhance.CacheableTransformerDecorator$1.transform(CacheableTransformerDecorator.java:38)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.CloningClassSpace$CloningClassLoader.findClass(CloningClassSpace.java:154)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.CloningClassSpace$CloningClassLoader.loadClass(CloningClassSpace.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.DependencyAnalyzer.visit(DependencyAnalyzer.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.DependencyAnalyzer.visit(DependencyAnalyzer.java:1)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInstanceBindingImpl.acceptTargetVisitor(ProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ElementAnalyzer.visit(ElementAnalyzer.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ElementAnalyzer.visit(ElementAnalyzer.java:1)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingImpl.acceptVisitor(BindingImpl.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule.configure(WireModule.java:77)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:168)
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildPlexusContainer(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:167)
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildPlexusContainer(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:141)
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.PlexusComponentProvider.<init>(PlexusComponentProvider.java:37)
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildComponentProvider(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:57)
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:91)
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:85)
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.newMavenEmbedder(MavenProjectLoader.java:148)
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:90)
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:84)
    at org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenPomModelGenerator.parse(MavenPomModelGenerator.java:34)
    at org.appformer.maven.support.PomModel$Parser.parse(PomModel.java:110)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildPomModel(KieBuilderImpl.java:509)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.getPomModel(KieBuilderImpl.java:486)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.init(KieBuilderImpl.java:149)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:208)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:184)
    at org.kie.internal.utils.KieHelper.getKieContainer(KieHelper.java:84)
    at org.kie.internal.utils.KieHelper.build(KieHelper.java:71)
    at com.ddmc.tag.drools.DroolsUtils.getKnowledgeBaseImplBySql(DroolsUtils.java:537)
    at com.ddmc.tag.drools.DroolsUtils.initBatchRuleSession(DroolsUtils.java:192)
    at com.ddmc.tag.drools.DroolsUtils.init(DroolsUtils.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1737)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.ddmc.TagServiceApplication.main(TagServiceApplication.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the stack trace, you're having an issue with an optional type -- https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/780#issuecomment-557577919 . Per that GH issue, this only stops the introspection and doesn't actually break anything. But if you want it to work you just need to include the missing dependency.

I'm unfamiliar with whatever library that is, but it might be maven-core. Drools includes maven integration and a maven plugin -- I'm unsure if you're using either, but it makes sense they'd be considered optional. If you're using them, you likely need to declare dependencies on them directly.

Comment: thanks,I don't know which dependence I lack.

Comment: Compare the dependencies from Drools and KIE with the jars which contain that missing class.

Comment: but why is it normal for me to run locally?  if the error is caused by a lack of dependencies, the local run should also have errors.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you "run locally" in your IDE and run elsewhere in a Jar, then your Jar is missing dependencies. Optional dependencies are often provided by your runtime container (IDE, Tomcat/Wildfly/etc), so your production container might be missing some configuration.